# ASP.NET Core Web API - The entity type 'IdentityUserRole<long>' requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I am implementing IdentityDbContext in ASP.NET Core Web API.

**IdentityModel:**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<long>
{
    public DateTime? LastLogin { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<long>
{
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<long>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

**AppDbContext:**

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, long, IdentityUserClaim<long>, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<long>, IdentityRoleClaim<long>, IdentityUserToken<long>>
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<ApplicationRole> ApplicationRole { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUserRole> ApplicationUserRole { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        this.SeedUsers(builder);
        this.SeedRoles(builder);
        this.SeedUserRoles(builder);

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(u => u.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            entity.HasIndex(u => u.Email).IsUnique();
        });
        builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(r => r.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            entity.HasIndex(r => r.Name).IsUnique();
        });
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>(userRole =>
        {
            userRole.HasKey(ur => new { ur.UserId, ur.RoleId });

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
                .IsRequired();

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.User)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                .IsRequired();
        });
    }
    private void SeedUsers(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            UserName = "Admin",
            NormalizedUserName = "ADMIN",
            Email = "admin@admin.com",
            SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D"),
            PhoneNumber = "+1234567890"
        };

        PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>();
        passwordHasher.HashPassword(user, "Admin*123");

        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasData(user);
    }

    private void SeedRoles(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().HasData(
            new ApplicationRole() { Name = "Admin", ConcurrencyStamp = "1", NormalizedName = "ADMIN" },
            new ApplicationRole() { Name = "User", ConcurrencyStamp = "2", NormalizedName = "USER" }
            );
    }

    private void SeedUserRoles(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<long>>().HasData(
            new IdentityUserRole<long>() { RoleId = 1, UserId = 1 }
            );
    }
}
```

The Id are auto-generated.

When I did **Add-Migration**, I got this error:

> The entity type 'IdentityUserRole' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to delete some code in `AppDbContext`:

**AppDbContext**

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, long, IdentityUserClaim<long>, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<long>, IdentityRoleClaim<long>, IdentityUserToken<long>>
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<ApplicationRole> ApplicationRole { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicationUserRole> ApplicationUserRole { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
           

            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(u => u.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
                entity.HasIndex(u => u.Email).IsUnique();
            });
            builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(r => r.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
                entity.HasIndex(r => r.Name).IsUnique();
            });
            
        }
        private void SeedUsers(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                UserName = "Admin",
                NormalizedUserName = "ADMIN",
                Email = "admin@admin.com",
                SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("D"),
                PhoneNumber = "+1234567890"
            };

            PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>();
            passwordHasher.HashPassword(user, "Admin*123");

            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasData(user);
        }

        private void SeedRoles(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().HasData(
                new ApplicationRole() { Name = "Admin", ConcurrencyStamp = "1", NormalizedName = "ADMIN" },
                new ApplicationRole() { Name = "User", ConcurrencyStamp = "2", NormalizedName = "USER" }
                );
        }

        private void SeedUserRoles(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<long>>().HasData(
                new IdentityUserRole<long>() { RoleId = 1, UserId = 1 }
                );
        }
    }
```

you can read this document to learn more about Customize Identity : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1